# Where do I find Jnanagarbha stotra?

Tags: stotra, kashmiri-shaivism

From [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=RZOjJgwS4r4C&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=jnanagarbha+stotra&source=bl&ots=ZDkRqypMFd&sig=c5F391N_IjKg5Scqd5wpsNN1XQY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi58OmYxevaAhWIrY8KHQn8AI8Q6AEwAnoECAAQNg#v=onepage&q=jnanagarbha%20stotra&f=false) link and a commentary on Pratyabhijnahridayam by revered acharya Kshemraj we find the following quote which is a spiritual technique (Shambhavopaye) leading to immediate realization if followed -

> O Mother, "when, in ordinary daily life one repels the actions of the mind and shatters dependence on the senses, by which one is enslaved, causing one to follow them according to their every wish, and instead diverts his senses towards God consciousness, then by your grace he instantly achieves that supreme state of God consciousness, which floods him with the unparalleled nectar of bliss (ananda)."

Now both the sources are claiming this verse belong to Jnanagarbha sotra. Where can I find the stotra?

Comment: Link not working.

Comment: The Stotra is dedicated to which deity? @Rohit.

Comment: @Rickross Parmeshwari